# Returning multiple values with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have searched related questions to this, but most of them are related to jquery ui which I am not using and the rest are not related to my problem.

I am using [this autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) [not the UI one] and am returning multiple values via SQL. I want to show just one value as an autocomplete which is working but the other two values I would like to use when the user clicks on the suggestion- it should redirect to another page with the other values.

For example: I have data returned:  `ABC 001 55`. 
ABC should be shown as suggested value in the list, but when the user clicks `ABC`, it should redirect the page with the other two values: `page/001/55/`

This is the code I have got till now and while the suggestions come up correctly [`data[0]`] I tried to use `data[1]` and `data[2]` to pass the other two data but this throws an undefined error:

PHP:

```
  foreach ($items as $item) {

            $value = $item['ABC'];
            $noID = $item['NoID'];
            $cID = $item['cID'];

            echo  $value . "\n";

        }
```

JQUERY:

```
  $('#f').autocomplete('redirect.php', {
        width: 500,
        max: 15,
        highlight: function(match, keywords) {
        keywords = keywords.split(' ').join('|');
        return match.replace(new RegExp("("+keywords+")", "gi"),'<b>$1</b>');
         },
        formatItem: function(data) {
            return data[0];
        }
        }).result(function(event, data) { 
            if (data) {
                //var noID = data[1];
                //var cID = data[2];
                //location.href = "anotherpage.php?s=" +noID+ "/" +cID;
                alert(data[0] + data[1] + data[2]); // <- data 1 and 2 are shown as undefined.
            }
     });
```

Comment: I'm familiar with php but you seem to only output the $value: `echo  $value . "\n"`.

Comment: Even if I echo the other two values, it still shows me the `undefined` error.

Comment: Looking at the source of the plugin, the data separator is `|`, so you should have something like `echo "$value|$noID|$cID\n";` (edit: i am NOT familiar with phph :o))

Comment: @Didier G., excellent. Thank you for the pointer. Can you please answer with the same reply so that I can accept and mark it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not "echo-ing" all the necessary values in your php script.

Looking at the source code of the plugin, the parsing method expects this:

```
Data1|Data2|Data3\n
Data1|Data2|Data3\n
Data1|Data2|Data3\n
```

I'm not familiar with php but your script should output something like this:

```
echo "$value|$noID|$cID\n";
```

---

For info, here is the parsing method from the plugin:

```
function parse(data) {
    var parsed = [];
    var rows = data.split("\n");
    for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = $.trim(rows[i]);
        if (row) {
            row = row.split("|");
            parsed[parsed.length] = {
                data: row,
                value: row[0],
                result: options.formatResult && options.formatResult(row, row[0]) || row[0]
            };
        }
    }
    return parsed;
};
```